# How to add Android Auto support for an already existing MAUI application With media palyer

Tags: android, .net-6.0, maui, android-auto

We are intergating some media player functionalities for Android Auto/Cars support with MAUI mobile application.

I am able to play some sample media with .MAUI for Android platform, But when I am giving support for Android AUTO/Cars, I am unable to see anything on the Android DHU(Android AUTO console). I did all the necessary configurations on the manifest file related to metadata with **com.google.android.gms.car.application**.

Could anyone help here with any samples for getting started with .MAUI with media player for Android AUTO support.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also implemented a `MediaBrowserService` as described in [Build media apps for cars](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media)? That is the component of your application that is used by Android Auto to display your application on the head unit.

Comment: Thanks, @Ben Sagome for the update. I already implemented MediaBrowser Service. Now I am able to see the app in the DHU. But when I am trying to play some sample audio file from a Mobile device, It's not playing the same on DHU. I am getting some error like : Unexcepecetd error and so on.